# sqoop data from sql server to hbase meet region servers dead

Tags: hbase, sqoop

i am trying to import data from sql server to hbase through sqoop.
the sqoop script is work,i tried with a small data and it worked.
but when i trying to use it import a huge data (20G) 
at first it shows that job is submitted,mapping 0%,reducing 0%.
after  server time later,the job is still in running statu.
so i  check the logs,it shows connection refused,caused by region servers dead,all servers dead.
i start up hbase again with start-hbase.sh,and it works for a while then dead,i don't know how to do about it.

do anyone meet this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the data from relational server to HDFS using the sqoop specifying the number of mappers using parameters -m/--num-mappers